# Join tables in ClickHouse without equal expressions

Tags: join, clickhouse

I need to join two tables with 'between' condition in ClickHouse without equal expressions.

How to implement this logic?

- I did:

```
select a.*, b.name
    from a join b
    on a.dt between b.start_dt and b.end_dt;
```

- Then got error

> Code: 403, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Invalid expression for JOIN ON. Expected equals expression...

Answer (score 3):

now JOIN in Clickhouse supports equi-join only https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-equi-join.php

You can use cartesian product and where

```sql
select a.*, b.name
from a , b
where a.dt between b.start_dt and b.end_dt;
```

it's absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help but if I need to join large tables, cartesian product maybe not the best solution.

Comment: You don't understand, in case of clickhouse there is no difference. Clickhouse puts the right table into memory BEFORE join (it is necessary for the JOIN itself).